# "$element.empty is not a function" with $modal Bootstrap in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm having some trouble trying to replicate an scenario in jsfiddle. I'm using $modal from bootstrap to try to open a modal window when clicking on an element in the screen and when I click on it, instead of getting the window I just get the backdrop and an error in the console "$element.empty is not a function".

I check the js for bootstrap and this is the code which is causing the error (line `$element.empty();`, but I have no idea what is causing it. Any ideas?

```
.directive('modalTransclude', function () {
    return {
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, controller, $transclude) {
        $transclude($scope.$parent, function(clone) {
          $element.empty();
          $element.append(clone);
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danaya/tqdxyzqf/3/) with the code, and this is the directive I'm using:

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ui.bootstrap']);

app.directive("myDir", ['$compile', '$modal', function($compile, $modal){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) {            
            
            var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
            circle.setAttribute('cx', 10);
            circle.setAttribute('cy', 10);
            circle.setAttribute('r', 5);            
            
            circle.setAttribute('ng-click', 'open()');
            
            element.append(circle);
            
            $compile(element)(scope);
        },
        controller: function($scope) {              
            $scope.open = function () {                 
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    template: '<div>I am a modal</div>'
                });
            };              
        },
        template:'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200"><image x="0" y="0" width="400" height="200" xlink:href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png"/></svg>'    
    }
}]);
```

In my application I'm not getting this error, and the only difference is I'm using bootstrap 0.13 instead of the 0.12 in jsfiddle (I can´t use 0.13 as it needs angularjs 1.3, which is not available in fiddle).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A sidenote: You *can* use Angular 1.3.x in JsFiddle, just add it as an "External resource". You may also want to run it "No wrap - in body".

Comment: Great! problem was in the library, I changed to 1.3 and it worked. Thanks!